# How to create an infinite nested dictionary in Python 3 through user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nested

I'm currently taking my first Python course, and have no background in CS. I'm working on a hypothetical program that incorporates small problems from our discussion topics and critical thinking assignments in order to practice using the code in a way that makes sense to me (I'm a publicist and photographer). At the moment, the program is a client database for a publicist to add client info, print a full client list, and calculate tax withholding.

I'm struggling to create an infinite nested dictionary that is populated through user input. I've searched online, but can't quite find a solution that meets my hypothetical requirements.

For the "ADD" branch of the program, I would like to be able to add new clients/info to the nested dictionary (client_info). The program asks the user a series of questions, such as client ID, band name, contract end date, pay, and management. I'm hoping to use some kind of loop so that the user can add a bunch of bands to the client_info dictionary, and the program will automatically update and create a new dictionary for each band within the client_info dictionary.

I first populated client_info with four bands and their info. Then I created empty dictionaries (with number assignments for each empty dictionary) and wrote individual code for each empty dictionary (10 total), but this meant I had a lot of code, and I couldn't figure out a way to recycle code to streamline the program.

I have also tried using initials for the bands instead of a number thinking that there might be an easy way to assign the client ID, but that failed miserably and I couldn't find a way to make the program run.

```
# Define dictionary for client information
client_info = {1: {'band' : 'colfax_speed_queen','email' :  'csq@colfaxspeedqueen.com', 'contract' : '20190808', 'pay' : int(800), 'mgmt' : 'MGI'},
         2: {'band' : 'the_ghoulies', 'email' : 'tg@theghoulies.com', 'contract' : '20191031', 'pay' : int(250), 'mgmt' : 'DIY'},
         3: {'band' : 'hail_satan', 'email' : 'hs@hailsatan.com', 'contract' : '20190606', 'pay' : int(700), 'mgmt' : 'APG'},
         4: {'band' : 'plastic_daggers', 'email' : 'pd@plasticdaggers.com', 'contract' : '20190420', 'pay' : int(1000), 'mgmt' : 'DIY'}}

# Pretend to create infinite nested dictionary for client information, but ultimately fail
c = 4
while c <= 19:
    c += 1
    client_info[c] = {}

# General greeting
print("Welcome to the client database.")

# Directions to use database
main_menu = str("""You can:
    PRINT your client list.
    ADD a new client to the database.
    Calculate your TAX withholding.""")
print(main_menu, "\nWhat would you like to do?")
access_client = input()

# Add client to database
elif access_client.lower() == 'add':

    while access_client.lower() == 'add':

        # Request user input for client id
        print("\nWhat is the client id?")

        # Update client id
        c = int(input())

        # Request user input for client_info[c]['band']
        print("What is the name of the band?")

        # Update client_info[c]['band']
        client_info[c]['band'] = input()

        # Request user input for client_info[c]['email']
        print("What is " + client_info[c]['band'] + "\'s email address?")

        # Update client_info[c]['email']
        client_info[c]['email'] = input()

        # Request user input for client_info[c]['contract']
        print("When does " + client_info[c]['band'] + "\'s contract end?")

        # Update client_info[c]['contract']
        client_info[c]['contract'] = int(input())

        # Request user input for client_info[c]['pay']
        print("What is your payment from " + client_info[c]['band'] + "?")

        # Update client_info[c]['pay']
        client_info[c]['pay'] = int(input())

        # Request user input for client_info[c]['mgmt']
        print("Who is managing " + client_info[c]['band'] + "?")

        # Update client_info[c]['mgmt']
        client_info[c]['mgmt'] = input()

        # Notify user that system has been updated with client information
        print("\nThank you for adding " + client_info[c]['band'] + "\'s information to the client database. The database has been updated.")
        print(client_info[c])
        print(client_info)

        # Ask user to add another client
        print("\nType ADD to add another client. Hit any other key to return to the main menu.")
        add_client = input()
        if add_client.lower() != 'add':
            break
    print(main_menu)
```

The while c <= 19 loop sort of works the way I want it to, but if the user doesn't know the last client id number, they could accidentally overwrite a previous entry. 
If you print the full dictionary, then any blank dictionaries through 20 will get printed as well. If I wanted to have the option to have 200 entries in my dictionary, it would be annoying to have all those blank dictionaries print out when I want to see the full client list. 
Since I currently have 4 entries in the dictionary, I have to have c = 4 above the while c <= 19 loop. (We haven't gone over how to save the content of user input at the moment, but I'm assuming that this would be an issue once I know how to save.) I would need to update the c = # every time I used the program. And if I use c = 0, it deletes the entries I've already saved in the dictionary.

I think I'm close, but it isn't as efficient as I would like it to be. I would appreciate any help you could give me as I'm a total noob and have no idea what I'm doing! 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than pre-populating your top level dictionary with empty inner dictionaries for clients you haven't entered yet, you should instead create each dictionary as you need it, just before you collect the information about the new client.

Your program can calculate the new client ID number automatically, using something like `len(client_info)` or `len(client_info) + 1` to get a new number based on how many records you already have. Here's a very brief example of this, with a much simplified client record:

```
client_info = {} # start empty

while True:
    new_client = {}
    name = input("what is the band's name? ")
    new_client['name'] = name
    new_client_id = len(client_info) # starts at zero, add 1 if you want the IDs to start at 1
    client_info[new_client_id] = new_client

    print("client added, client_info is now", client_info)
```

You might also consider using a list for the top level of the data structure, if you never remove clients from it. Instead of generating an ID and indexing with it to assign the new client record, you'd just `append` the record to the list of clients. The ID would be implicit, as the position the client ended up in the list.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I tried this out for a different assignment and it did the trick, but for that situation, I started out using an empty dictionary. I'm about to mess around with this hypothetical program and create some functions since this is what we're going over this week in my course. I'm interested to see how using this format with a function will help with the flow of the program. Thanks again for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 0):

You could consider to do something like the raw example here below:

```
ids = client_info.keys()
next_c = max(ids) + 1

fields = ['band', 'email', 'contract', 'pay', 'mgmt']

for field in fields:
    print("Enter ", field)
    client_info[next_c][field] = input()
```

The basic idea is to find the next c to use as id looking for the max actual id + 1.
This allow to avoid to use already used ids, but not if last was deleted. To avoid reusing the already used id instead of deleting the object, set it to `None` (for eample):

```
client_info = {1: None, .....}
```

Declare the fields you need to populate in a list, so you can iterate over it ad keep code DRY.

---

This is just a starting point for further customisations.
For example, customising the answers:

```
fields_2 = {'band': 'What is the name of the band?', 'email': 'What is the band email address?', 'contract':'When does contract ends?', 'pay':'What is your payment from the band?', 'mgmt':'Who is managing the band'}
for field, answer in fields_2.items():
    print(answer)
    # client_info[next_c][field] = input()
```

So, the user could see:

```
# What is the name of the band?
# What is the band email address?
# When does contract ends?
# What is your payment from the band?
# Who is managing the band?
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I'm still looking into this and testing out different suggestions, so I will get back to you with more feedback soon. I'm just a little slow to get everything done.